dax expression to count all orders by the customers who buy a brand at least one time
I have a sales fact table like this :
sales sample fact table



IdCustomer
OrderKey
Product
product code
Brand




25
12256
product_x
514545
brand1


25
12256
product_y
514546
brand2


26
13254
product_z
514541
brand3


27
13242
product_y
514546
brand2


25
15529
product_x
514545
brand1


25
15529
product_h
514549
brand4


25
15529
product_y
514546
brand2


27
17546
product_h
514549
brand4


27
17546
product_g
514544
brand5


25
12250
product_x
514545
brand1


27
12349
product_y
514546
brand2


25
12506
product_z
514541
brand3



the result i want is :
result pivot table
I want to calculate the Total Customers Orders , the total count of all orders by customers, who buy that brand ( in the filter context) at least one time. Not the total orders by the customer for only that brand ( column Orders)
I write this measure : it's wrong in the grand total.
CALCULATE(SUMX(SUMMARIZE(Sales,Sales[OrdersKey]),1),ALL(Dim_Brand[Brand])

can anyone help?
Thanks,
I write this measure : it's wrong in the grand total( due to the ALL function)
CALCULATE(SUMX(SUMMARIZE(Sales,Sales[OrdersKey]),1),ALL(Dim_Brand[Brand])


why customer order for 0025 of brand 1 is 4? what's the calculation logic?

Please don't paste data as an image.

@Ryan because customer 0025 , made 4 different orders in total. 3 of brand 1 , but 4 in total( all brand). That's exactly what i need to calculate

maybe you can try this
MEASURE =
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Table'[Brand] ),
    ALL ( 'Table' ),
    'Table'[IdCustomer] = MAX ( 'Table'[IdCustomer] )
)

Measure 2 = sumx(VALUES('Table'[IdCustomer]),[measure])



Try the following Measure:
Total Customer Orders = 
  var customers = DISTINCT(Sales[IdCustomer])
  return 
    CALCULATE(
      DISTINCTCOUNTNOBLANK(Sales[OrderKey]),
      REMOVEFILTERS(Dim_Brand[Brand]),
      Sales[IdCustomer] IN customers
    )

